# Defining ideal of a Schubert variety as a kernel

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, flag-varieties, schubert-calculus, schubert-varieties

Consider the Plücker embedding of the variety of complete flags in $\mathbb C^n$: $$F_n\subset\mathbb P(\bigwedge\nolimits^1\mathbb C^n)\times\dots\times\mathbb P(\bigwedge\nolimits^{n-1}\mathbb C^n).$$ It is given by the Plücker ideal $I\subset \mathbb C[\{X_{i_1,\dots,i_k}\}]$ where $1\le k\le n-1$ and $1\le i_1<\dots<i_k\le n$.

Now consider a permutation $w\in\mathcal S_n$ and the corresponding Schubert variety $Y_w\subset F_n$. A set of generators of the defining ideal $I_w\supset I$ of $Y_w$ is well known, one adds a certain set of Plücker variables to $I$. For quite some time I've assumed that $I_w$ can also be described as the kernel of certain map, similarly to $I$. Namely, one considers the $n\times n$ matrix $Z_w$ with $(Z_w)_{i,j}$ equal to the variable $z_{i,j}$ if $j\ge w(i)$ and to 0 otherwise. The map $$\varphi_w:\mathbb C[\{X_{i_1,\dots,i_k}\}]\to\mathbb C[z_{i,j}]_{1\le i,j\le n}$$ then takes $X_{i_1,\dots,i_k}$ to the minor of $Z_w$ spanned by rows $1,\dots,k$ and columns $i_1,\dots,i_k$.

Now, after reconsidering, I still believe that $I_w$ is the kernel of $\varphi_w$, this seems to follow readily from the Bruhat decomposition. However, I'm a bit taken aback by not being able to find a single reference for or even an explicit mentioning of this. Can someone provide me with such a reference (or disprove the claim)?

P.S. A reference for the analogous statement in the Grassmannian case would work just as well.

Comment: @LSpice Thank you for the edit but please cf. the notation here, for instance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/460128/defining-ideal-of-a-schubert-variety-as-a-kernel#comment1192250_460128), I think that the quality of mathematics notation on Wikipedia should discourage one from using it as a reference; the notation there is analogous to writing $+_{n = 1}^\infty n^{-2} = \frac{\pi^2}6$ (or, perhaps more strictly analogous, something like $\cap_{n = 1}^\infty (n, \infty) = \emptyset$).  But it is certainly common, so, if you prefer it, then please feel free to revert, with my apologies for an unwelcome edit.

Comment: @LSpice I'll just let it be, it's no big deal. I kind of see your point although there is a meaningful difference between an exterior power of a space and, say, a sum or a tensor product of a collection of spaces. I also never had a reviewer or coauthor complain about $\wedge$ which kind of made me used to it. Btw, some people also use $\Lambda$ for this which I'm personally no fan of.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/460128/defining-ideal-of-a-schubert-variety-as-a-kernel#comment1192257_460128), nor am I fond of $\Lambda$!  I checked what I consider a more reputable source for notation than Wikipedia, the [Encyclopedia of Math](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra), and they agree with your $\wedge$ notation.